# how to increase ubuntu partition size from inside ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, dell

i have ubuntu 12.04 installed alongside windows 8.
i gave only 15 gb partition to ubuntu while installing. now i need more space as 15gb is too less . Is there any way that I can increase my ubuntu partition space so that i dont need to install ubuntu all over again.
thanks in advance.

i have this link
http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/
should i try this or there is some other way.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot increase the partition while Ubuntu is running. However you do not need to re-install Ubuntu either. Simply get a live USB or Ubuntu install disk and select the "Try Ubuntu without installing" option. You can then use Gparted to resize your partitions. If you do not have a spare USB or install CD then I don't think there is a lot you can do...

Comment: i have installed gparted on ubuntu. so can i do from that or i only need live usb or cd?

Comment: You should be able to just boot off of the live USB or Cd and search for gparted in the dash. If it is not found open a terminal window (ctrl+alt+t) and type sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gparted

Comment: and if i use live cd for partition will there be any loss of data from the drive from where i am taking memory?

Answer (score 0):

The post which you provided is allright, and it actually mentions that you need to boot from live CD/USB to resize your root partition (otherwise you can't unmount it). This link is probably even more instructive as it talks about re-allocating space between partitions which is your case: http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=moving-space-between-partitions.

The possibility of data loss in process is very small but if you have any life-or-death data on any of the partitions, you'd better back it up.

What is quite possible though is that your boot will get broken as you are moving the start of your root partition where the grub files are, so boot.img may not find them. You will then end up in GRUB rescue mode which isn't a very big issue though, it's utterly fixable.